# How to block startallback auto update pop-up?

Tags: windows-11, start-menu

startallback auto update checker pop-up is annoying. It brings itself to top even when I'm playing games fullscreen.

[image]

startallback doesn't seem to have a config option to disable auto update.

So I tried to block network access through windows firewall

[image]

However, this doesn't seem to stop auto update checker. Did I configure anything wrong or is there any better way to block this auto update checker?

Comment: 1. Look in Task Manager for StartAllBack tasks, i.e., update, and disable. 2. Revert to version *prior* to 3.6.4, which inaugurated autoupdate: https://www.startallback.com/

Comment: Keep in mind reverting to a previous version or staying on a specific version might cause incompatibilities with the Windows build you do have installed. It’s being updated for a reason. You really should update StartAllBack.

Answer (score -1):

Uninstall it and look for other 3rd party software that does what you need out of it's feature set, and isn't so hostile toward it's user base with a default setting of "p*ss everybody off".

It does have an entry in Task Scheduler, but disabling/deleting it doesn't stop it from happening (it's coded into the app itself as well). I've emailed the author regarding this, which naturally vanished into the ether.

I ended up uninstalling it for the same reason. An available update shouldn't also equate to a Nag screen.

**Update:**

Try blocking this file with your windows firewall:

[image]